# Replace raw data and cut it automatically in different reports

Tags: reporting

I have a raw data in excel and I have to cut that excel into different excels that contain different filters and columns each from that raw data. Was wondering which system I can use, so I can do it automatically, as I have to do this on a monthly basis.

My idea was to have a main report which I will replace the info with every month and then make this system cut the data into several files with the specifics I need on each.

I though of Excel Macros but, I know there must be something else out there that can help me. I learn super fast though so anything that you could bring to my attention I will start learning.